# ¿Agregar una nueva clave y valor a todos los objetos de un array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, objeto

Hola a todos de ante mano muchas gracias por sus repuestas y comentarios estoy intentando lo siguiente:

Tengo un array de Objetos en el cual quiero agregar una nueva clave y valor a todos los objetos, tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
const pension = [
  {cat_bank_id: 91,cat_discount: 1,clabe: "901",curp: "ASDA",name: "asda",percentage: "12"},
  {cat_bank_id: 92,cat_discount: 1,clabe: "902",curp: "ASDB",name: "asdb",percentage: "12"}
];
```

Quiero lograr lo siguiente:

```
const pension = [
  {cat_bank_id: 91,cat_discount: 1,clabe: "901",curp: "ASDA",name: "asda",percentage: "12", employee_id: 212},
  {cat_bank_id: 92,cat_discount: 1,clabe: "902",curp: "ASDB",name: "asdb",percentage: "12", employee_id: 212}
];
```

Estoy intentando de la siguiente manera:

```
const pension = [
  {cat_bank_id: 91,cat_discount: 1,clabe: "901",curp: "ASDA",name: "asda",percentage: "12"},
  {cat_bank_id: 92,cat_discount: 1,clabe: "902",curp: "ASDB",name: "asdb",percentage: "12"}
];
const employee_id = 212;

const test = pension.map(pension => {
    return pension.key3 = employee_id;
});
console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes crear un nuevo objeto o anexarlo. El spreed operator puede ser de utilidad.

```js
const pension = [
  {cat_bank_id: 91,cat_discount: 1,clabe: "901",curp: "ASDA",name: "asda",percentage: "12"},
  {cat_bank_id: 92,cat_discount: 1,clabe: "902",curp: "ASDB",name: "asdb",percentage: "12"}
];
const employee_id = 212;

const test = pension.map(pension => {
    // spread operator ( ... )
    return {...pension,employee_id };
});
console.log(test)
```

Otra manera de hacerlo:

```js
const pension = [
  {cat_bank_id: 91,cat_discount: 1,clabe: "901",curp: "ASDA",name: "asda",percentage: "12"},
  {cat_bank_id: 92,cat_discount: 1,clabe: "902",curp: "ASDB",name: "asdb",percentage: "12"}
];
const employee_id = 212;

const test = pension.map(pension => {
    pension['employee_id']=employee_id 
    return pension;
});
console.log(test)
```